# An easy calculated limit looks like the one of Euler–Mascheroni constant.

Tags: euler-mascheroni-constant

I have here the known series of natural logarthem.

$$\ln \left( \frac {1}{1-x} \right)=x+\frac {x^2}{2}+\frac {x^3}{3}+\frac {x^4}{4}+\frac {x^5}{5}+\cdots \tag 1$$

and

$$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac {x^2}{2}+\frac {x^3}{3}-\frac {x^4}{4}+\frac {x^5}{5}-\cdots \tag 2$$

Subtract $(2)$ from $(1)$

$$\ln\left(\frac {1}{1-x}\right)-\ln(1+x)=x^2 +\frac {x^4}{2}+\frac {x^6}{3}+\frac {x^8}{4}+\cdots \tag 3$$

Now if we let $x \to 1$

$$\lim_{x \to 1}\left[\ln\left(\frac 1{1-x}\right)-(x^2 +\frac {x^4}{2}+\frac {x^6}{3}+\frac {x^8}{4}+\cdots)\right]=\ln (2) \tag 4$$

So what is the difference between this and Euler–Mascheroni constant limit?

$$\gamma=\lim_{n \to\infty} \left(-\ln (n)+\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac 1 k \right) \tag 5$$

I am sure that $\gamma \neq -\ln(2)$

There must be a problem that I can not recognize.

Comment: $(4)$ is wrong.  The limit is $\pm\infty$, depending on which side you take the limit.  Also, $(5)$ is very different from $(4)$

Comment: I agree with you @SimpleArt.

Comment: In (4), isn't $\ln\left({1\over1-x^2}\right) - ...$ required?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have four different quantities all diverging
as $n\to\infty$ and $x\to1^-$.
Whether the difference between any two of these diverges or
converges to any particular value depends on exactly how each one diverges.

You can make $\ln \left( \frac {1}{1-x} \right)$ and $ln(n)$ diverge
in exactly the same way by setting them equal, that is,
by setting $x = 1 - \frac1n$.
Now compare $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac 1 k$ with 
$x^2 +\frac {x^4}{2}+\frac {x^6}{3}+\frac {x^8}{4}+\cdots$
for various increasing values of $n$.
You may notice that when $n = 1$,
$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac 1 k - \left(x^2 +\frac {x^4}{2}+\frac {x^6}{3}+\frac {x^8}{4}+\cdots\right) = 1$,
and that for larger values of $n$ this difference does not approach zero
but rather continues to grow.

This "excess" value of $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac 1 k$
explains why $\gamma > -\ln(2)$.

Comment: It seems to me For larger values of $n$ , $x \to 1$ which reduce the difference between the two series, and also the value of $x < 1$ always then the growth is going down. the picture still not clear to me. thank you for your answer +1.

Comment: Both series grow infinitely large through very different mechanisms, so any idea that the difference between them should ever approach zero is a mistaken intuition. On the contrary, your own calculations indicate that the difference should approach a number slightly larger than $1.27$.