# Why does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} (H_n-\log(n) - \gamma)$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, divergent-series, harmonic-numbers

Suppose $\gamma$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) .

Let $\gamma_n:=H_n-\ln(n)$.

Then $\gamma=\lim_{n \to \infty} \gamma_n.$

I have this summation $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\gamma_n-\gamma)$$

I would like to know if this summation converges or not.

If I calculate the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty}(\gamma_n-\gamma)$ it is clear that the result is zero.
but it seems to me it diverges, so how to find the result if it converges and how to prove it.

**EDIT**

Now we are sure it diverges by using the harmonic formula shown in Iqcd answer.

But I think if we speed up $\gamma_n$ to go quickly to $\gamma$ it will converges by changing $n$ to $n^2$ so we have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\gamma_{(n^2)}-\gamma)$.

And it seems we have new function here diverges at $x=1$ $$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\gamma_{(n^x)}-\gamma)$$

at $x \to +\infty$ , $f(x)=1-\gamma$

Comment: To make your question better, what is $H_n$?. "but it seems to me it diverges", why do you think so?

Comment: Me too, but my question was to know how to prove it.

Comment: May be it is interesting, that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=4^n}^{4^{n+1}-1} (H_k - \log(k) -\gamma) \to \log(2) $ (heuristically...)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms, it seems we are close to something see this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1912650/an-easy-calculated-limit-looks-like-the-one-of-euler-mascheroni-constant

Answer (score 5):

We have (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation))

$$\tag{$*$}\label{eq1}H_n=\log(n)+\gamma+\frac1{2n}+O(n^{-2})$$

so

$$\sum_{n\leq x}\left\{H_n-\log(n)-\gamma\right\}
=\sum_{n\leq x}\left\{\frac1{2n}+O(n^{-2})\right\},$$

and therefore the series diverges.

**ADDED** (after the edit): let us define the function

$$f(x;N):=\sum_{n\leq N}\left\{H_{n^x}-\log(n^x)-\gamma\right\},$$

so that $f(x;N)\to f(x)$ when $N\to\infty$. Again by \eqref{eq1} we see that

$$f(x;N)=\sum_{n\leq N}\left\{\log(n^x)+\gamma+\frac1{2n^x}-\log(n^x)-\gamma+O(n^{-2x})\right\}
=\sum_{n\leq N}\left\{\frac1{2n^x}+O(n^{-2x})\right\}.$$

Since $\sum n^{-p}$ converges iff $p>1$, we see that $f(x)$ converges iff $x>1$.

Comment: If you don't mind see the edit.

Comment: I've added the convergence of $f(x)$. Is that what you asked?

Comment: $H_n = \int_1^{n+1} \frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor}dx$ so $\log(n)-H_n=  \int_1^{n+1} (\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor})dx$ and $-\gamma = \int_1^\infty (\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor})dx$ while $\gamma_n-\gamma =\int_{n+1}^\infty (\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\lfloor x \rfloor})dx =\int_{n+1}^\infty \int_{\lfloor x \rfloor}^{x} \frac{-2}{y^2} dydx = \int_{n+1}^\infty (\frac{-1}{y^2} + \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{y^3}))dy = \frac{1}{2n+1}+\mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{n^3})$ @Pentapolis

Comment: @iqcd, yes that is what I was asking about. so the function $f(x)$ has a real curve for $1<x<+\infty$.